# Why does -[UIColor setFill] work without referring to a drawing context?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, graphics, uicolor

It escapes me why this code, inside `drawRect:`, works:

```
UIBezierPath *buildingFloor = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
// draw the shape with addLineToPoint
[[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0] setFill]; // I'm sending setFill to UIColor object?
[buildingFloor fill]; // Fills it with the current fill color
```

My point is, the `UIColor` object gets a message `setFill` and then somehow the stack understands that this `UIColor` will now be the fill color, isn't this just weird and wrong? At the very least I would expect setting fill by calling some `CGContext` method... But now instead of representing a color, `UIColor` goes on and does something to change the context of my drawing.

Could someone explain what is happening behind the scenes, because I'm totally lost here?

I did check out these references before posting:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My point is, UIColor object gets a message setFill and then somehow the stack understands that this UIColor will now be the fill color, isn't this just weird and wrong? At the very least I would expect setting fill by calling some CGContext method... But now instead of representing a color, UIColor goes on and does something to change the context of my drawing.

It is because all this is taking place within the *current* CGContext. That is why your code works only if there *is* a current CGContext (as there is, for example, in `drawRect:` or in a `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` block).

It will probably help you a lot, at this stage of your iOS study, to read the Drawing chapter of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_contexts

Comment: Thanks a bunch @matt, especially for the link, it'll be immensely useful for me :)

Comment: Your book was really helpful. Finally someone broke down the concepts of graphic contexts and UIKit vs. CoreGraphics in a way that made sense! Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! I found the same thing confusing at first too, and that's why I put so much effort into explaining it clearly.

Answer (score 7):

The implementation of `UIColor setFill` is written to get the current graphics context and then to set the color on that current context. Essentially it does this for you:

```
UIColor *color = ... // some color
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
```

Comment: I do appreciate that it does that, but I find it Weird that it does, the cognitive dissonance comes from the fact that `UIColor` is a `color` object, not a `context` object.

Comment: The whole point of methods like `setFill` is to be a convenience when working with the current context. Also look at methods like the `NSString drawAtPoint:` (a category method of `NSString`). It is also a convenience method to make it easier to use higher level classes with the lower level Core Graphics API.